# Is it possible that jQuery transition does not work on a heavy webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transition

I am trying to use this solution for transition on my webpages:
http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

In fact it does not work well and like broken and changes slowly.  I tried it with an empty webpage and it worked better. I know my webpage is really heavy, so should I not use this transition thing? Or this specific solution isn't good enough.

Answer (score 2):

for heavy animations, it's time to go for GSAP, could be 20X faster and can be used as a jquery plugin, no need to change your jquery code using animate:

http://www.greensock.com/jquery-gsap-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for your post. As I'm not good at jQuery. I didn't understand it well.  should I only replace the GSAP tags with jQuery ones and thats it? Or I should change the code too? I am using a template which is a single html file and slides to different sections.  Anyway Thanks again and I guess I have to make a separate post about using this plugin.

Comment: Read 'usage' section here: http://www.greensock.com/jquery-gsap-plugin/  it is really easy to use. You can download specific files on top left of provided link: "get GSAP" link and choose javascript

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the performance of the PC.
Are you using CSS shadows, like box-shadow or text-shadow on your elements?
Are you using "live" or "on" for your elements' events?

Comment: well yes. I have lots some CSS shadows on my elements.  Actually I used CSS3 in most of the elements. Also jQuery and CSS animations. What do you mean by "live" "on"? I'm using xampp to check my files.

Comment: When you bind a function to an event in jQuery (like click) you use $(element).click, right? I thought you used $(element).live("click",....), that uses more cpu.